# How to export data from multiple emails to Excel workbook but different worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, worksheet

I want to export data from selected Outlook emails to a workbook. Each email's data (subject, body, etc.) should be stored in a different worksheet.

I'm trying to edit this macro because it is almost what I need—and especially the part of `olFormatHTML` and `WordEditor`—because of split.

The idea is

1. Select multiple emails in Outlook
2. Open file path
3. Data for each email selected will be stored in a single worksheet from file opened

The issue with the macro is in this third part

1. From the selected items, the macro does a loop and just takes the first email selected,
2. The data is stored in different workbooks; it should be stored in the same workbook that I opened.

```vb
Public Sub SplitEmail() 
    
    Dim rpl As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim txt As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    '----------------------------
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
        
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
       
    For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
        
        '----------------------------------------------
        Set itm = GetCurrentItem() 'A)I think the issuefrom selecting 1 item is located here
    
        '|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

        sPath = "C:\Users\Ray\"
        sFile = sPath & "Macro.xlsm"

        If Not itm Is Nothing Then
            Set rpl = itm.Reply
            rpl.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            'rpl.Display
        End If
            
        Set objDoc = rpl.GetInspector.WordEditor
        txt = objDoc.Content.Text
    
        '||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
        
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile) 'B) tried to move it to the beginning and macro doesn't work
        
        '||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

        For i = LBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1) To UBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1)
            wb.Worksheets(x).Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Split(txt, Chr(13))(i) 'B)emails in different sheet but no same workbook
        Next i    
            
    '------------------------------------------------------
    Next x
       
End Sub


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
    Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    GetCurrentItem.UnRead = False
    Set objApp = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an update to this macro
as macro do loop in `For x` it open the file x times,
and then close it and open again instead of working on the first workbook opened
but the macro leaves open instances
here is the current code

```
Public Sub SplitEmail()


    Dim rpl As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim txt As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    '----------------------------
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
    
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
   
For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
    
    '----------------------------------------------
    
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim GetCurrentItem As Object
        Set objApp = Application
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(x)
        Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        End Select
        
        GetCurrentItem.UnRead = False
        Set objApp = Nothing
    
    '-----------------------------------------------
    Set itm = GetCurrentItem


    sPath = "C:\Users\Ray\"
    sFile = sPath & "Macro.xlsm"
   
    
    If Not itm Is Nothing Then
    
        'de lo contrario, se crea un Reply del correo en formato HTML
        Set rpl = itm.Reply
        rpl.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        'rpl.Display
    End If
        
    
    Set objDoc = rpl.GetInspector.WordEditor
    txt = objDoc.Content.Text

    '||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    xlApp.Windows("Macro.xlsm").Activate
    'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    '||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

    

    
        For i = LBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1) To UBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1)
            wb.Worksheets(x).Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Split(txt, Chr(13))(i)
        Next i
        
    xlApp.Windows("Macro.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
        xlApp.Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
'------------------------------------------------------



Next x
'------------------------------------------------------


'the instances should closed but not working, instances are empty

        For Each wb In xlApp
           wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

done, I added `xlApp.Quit` after saving files and deleted the last part `For Each wb In xlApp...`

Answer (score 0):

`GetCurrentItem` is unnecessary. Open Excel outside of the loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitEmail()
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFile As String
    
    sPath = "C:\Users\Ray\"
    sFile = sPath & "Macro.xlsm"
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    
    '----------------------------
    Dim myOlExp As explorer
    Dim myOlSel As selection
        
    Set myOlExp = ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.selection
    
    Dim rpl As MailItem
    
    Dim x As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim objDoc As Word.document
    Dim txt As String
    
    Dim foundFlag As Boolean
    
    For x = 1 To myOlSel.count
        
        If myOlSel(x).Class = olMail Then
            
            Set rpl = myOlSel(x).Reply
            rpl.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            'rpl.Display
                
            Set objDoc = rpl.GetInspector.WordEditor
            txt = objDoc.content.Text
            
            For i = LBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1) To UBound(Split(txt, Chr(13)), 1)
                
                foundFlag = False
                
                With wb
                
                    For j = 1 To .Sheets.count
                        If .Worksheets(j).Name = "Sheet" & x Then
                            foundFlag = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    
                    If foundFlag = False Then
                        .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.count)).Name = "Sheet" & x
                    End If
                    
                    .Worksheets(x).range("A" & i + 1).Value = Split(txt, Chr(13))(i)
                
                End With
                
            Next i
        End If
    Next x
    
End Sub
```